# Updating a mysql table when clicking a link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, insert, onclick

I need to update a MySQL table when the user clicks a link.

Here's the link:

```
<a href='moreinfo.html' onclick="moreInfo();">More info</a>
```

If the user clicks it, I need to update table user with a 'yes' in field MoreInfo.

And here's the function:

```
function moreInfo(){

   info = 'yes';
   username ='user@user.com'; // coming from the session

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "more.php",
            data: "info="+info+"&username="+username+"",


        success: function(msg){ 
                alert(msg);

        }
    });
}
```

more.php

```
<?php 
//not updating the database yet, just echoing for testing purposes

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $info= $_POST['info'];
    echo $username;
    echo "<br>".$info;
?>
```

What I get in the alert of the function is: `<br>`

Is my aproach correct? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: @user712027: Could you show some code?

Comment: @user712027 Please explain a little what exactly you want to do? What do you mean by passing info? Are you trying to store data through ajax?

Comment: updated the post with more info, please tell me if it is more clear now. Thanks

Comment: Update the table user for all the rows? Or for a particular user? If it's just a particular user, are you using sessions, or how do you know which user is clicking that link?

Comment: updated the post with some code, please have a look. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database access needs to occur in PHP.  Soo...

1. So write a PHP file that will take a parameter for the current user and update the DB as necessary.  Have it echo something.  Can be as small as success/failure flag, but the ajax that calls should get some response data.
2. In javascript write some ajax to call upon this PHP file to get teh database access done. The javascript should probably also report some type of confirmation on the page.

These are the most common options for accessing MySQL in PHP.  The PHP standard manual is fantastic.  If you aren't using it yet I highly recommend!

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: what you have so far looks good, with the minor correction.  once all is said and done you might want to just put something like `Update successful` immediately below the link to indicate the database update was successful.  more importantly tho, work on that database update.